# visual studio Express 2015 for Windows Desktop 編集画面でインデントの破線が出てしまいます。

Tags: visual-studio

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

うっかりショートカットキーを押してしまったみたいで、
このような画面になってしまいました。

解除方法はありますか？
よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

初期設定ならば`Ctrl+R`→`Ctrl+W`で[戻せます](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ja-JP/1b37768b-894c-4092-b7e5-8939b3e360da?forum=vsgeneralja)

Answer (score 2):

[スペースの表示](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vstipsjpn/2008/04/08/003/)機能が有効になっています。
[編集] - [詳細] - [スペースの表示]で解除できます。